# How do I adjust the default "Displaying events until" on an embedded agenda

Tags: iframe, google-calendar-api

I have an embedded google calendar (agenda) on my website.
Currently it defaults to showing all events in the next two months.
How do I change this to show all events in the next six months?

Here is my embed code generated from my calendar settings

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;showNav=0&amp;showDate=0&amp;showPrint=0&amp;showTabs=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;mode=AGENDA&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=fgltphnkd8mvpnvu7ecp1cjpr8%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%238C500B&amp;ctz=Australia%2FPerth" style="border-width:0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Note the various `option=value` pairs. Is there any documentation for these?

I'm looking for a *start-date* - *end-date* type option?

Comment: When you check the [parameters from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#parameters), there are actually `timeMax` and `timeMin`. Upper bound (exclusive) and lower bound (inclusive) for an event's start and end time.

Comment: I thought you'd solved it for me but alas no :-( That documentation seems to apply to the API not the embedding URL. If I add timeMax and timeMin to the <iframe src= argument nothing changes. You can see it in action here: www.windwanderer.com.au

Comment: This is what I want but it doesn't seem to work any more: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/91256